# How to add FPS to Debug gauges in XCode 5?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

When running in debug mode, I can see CPU usage and memory usage, but how do I add FPS to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FPS gauge doesn't come up when you're running the simulator, only when you're running on a device. So be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I didn't realise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing an OpenGL ES enabled app, you should see an FPS debug gauge as you run your app.

If you want to see the FPS but aren't developing an OpenGL ES application, you can use the [CoreAnimation instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/CoreAnimationInstrument/CoreAnimationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH36-SW1) from the Instruments developer application (which can be launched from Xcode).

Comment: Where would I see it? I seem to remember seeing it when I was running XCode 4.5.x but after upgrading I can't see it, in the debug nav when running, there's just the CPU and Memory usage gauges, there must be a way to add more gauges in there but can't see where.

Comment: I think the FPS should come up there automatically if Xcode detects you're using OpenGL ES. It's not showing any more information than you could get from Instruments though, so you could use that instead.